Grafana Grouped transformation on Loki query: Not able to display data if only a single value is returned by query
I have the following query (some checks included to filter only real users):
sum by(remote_addr) (count_over_time({app="ingress-nginx"} | logfmt | host_name != `` | remote_user != "-" | status != 401 | host_name != "-" | request = `/` | remote_addr != `` | http_user_agent != `` | http_user_agent !~ `.*bot.*` | proxy_upstream_name != `` | http_user_agent !~ `.*crawl.*` [$__interval]))

with "Series to rows" transformation applied.
This essentially lists all visitors of my deployed Applications.
This is what the result looks like before trying to group and calculated the number of visits of each user/IP:

And here after grouping:

Now the issue is, that I am not able to group anything, if only a single visitor/ip is returned by the query. The possibility to "Group by Metric" is not available anymore.
Here the example when only a single value is returned:

The censored part is the single IP that has been returned by the query, and I cannot apply the grouping anymore. If I enable the group transformation now, it'd just say "no data" since there is nothing to group after.
Am I approaching this issue in a wrong way or is this just not possible to do?
I guess it might work if there was a possibility to somehow add some default dummy value which would allow me to group again?
Please let me know what you think, I unfortunately can't come up with a solution for this and it seems like no one has run into this issue so far.

Coincidentally, I've noticed the transformation "Time Series to Table Transform" and it works like a charm. I am using Grafana v10.2.2 and it's currently in BETA version but no issues occurred so far.
Solution: don't use "Series to Rows" but "Time Series to Table Transform".
